# clarification regarding details of internship

Tags: internship, email

Recently I received a positive reply from the professor regarding summer research internship. How should I go on writing a mail to ask about the stipend and any prerequisite knowledge I should have before starting the internship?

Comment: Did your professor mention an onboarding process?

Comment: No professor didn't mention anything like that

Comment: Is this software related ?

Comment: Yes computer science

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

> Dear Professor
>
> Thank you for your offer of a summer research internship. Is there a stipend associated with this and if so, how much is it?
>
> Also is there anything else I should know before starting? Do I need to do some preliminary research of my own?
>
> Yours,

should be adequate.

Don't be afraid to come straight to the point. It's of benefit to you both to have clear communications.

Comment: A question. An answer.  This must not be the internet.